# iPhone: Anyway of streaming WMA?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, streaming, media, wma

Does anyone have a solution or a possible open library that can be used to stream WMA radio station streams on iPhone?

I know for a fact that there are Apps out which are able to do this.

Any pointers on where to start?

Comment: "I know for a fact that there are Apps out which are able to do this." Such as...? Are you certain they're not converting the stream on a server somewhere, or using an alternate format?

Comment: Well? Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

In order to play WMA, look into using the ffmpeg library. I'm not sure if it can stream as well, but I'm pretty sure it can play the format.